# Regex (JavaScript): match feet and/or inches

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm trying to match **feet and inches** but I can't manage to get "and/or" so if first half is correct it validates:

Code: (in javascript)

```
var pattern = "^(([0-9]{1,}\')?([0-9]{1,}\x22)?)+$";

function testing(input, pattern) {
        var regex = new RegExp(pattern, "g");
        console.log('Validate '+input+' against ' + pattern);
        console.log(regex.test(input));
    }
```

Valid tests should be:

- `1'`
- `1'2"`
- `2"`
- `2` (assumes inches)

Not valid should be:
* anything else including empty
* `1'1'`

But my regex **matches** the invalid `1'1'`.

Comment: Tip: Do not use `/g` with a regex that is used in `RegExp#test()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `+` at the end (which allows more than one instance of feet/inches right now) and check for an empty string or illegal entries like `1'2` using a separate [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). I've also changed the regex so group 1 contains the feet and group 2 contains the inches (if matched):

```
^(?!$|.*\'[^\x22]+$)(?:([0-9]+)\')?(?:([0-9]+)\x22?)?$
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mL8fD7/2).

**Explanation:**

```
^          # Start of string
(?!        # Assert that the following can't match here:
 $         # the end of string marker (excluding empty strings from match)
|          # or
 .*\'      # any string that contains a '
 [^\x22]+  # if anything follows that doesn't include a "
 $         # until the end of the string (excluding invalid input like 1'2)
)          # End of lookahead assertion
(?:        # Start of non-capturing group:
 ([0-9]+)  # Match an integer, capture it in group 1
 \'        # Match a ' (mandatory)
)?         # Make the entire group optional
(?:        # Start of non-capturing group:
 ([0-9]+)  # Match an integer, capture it in group 2
 \x22?     # Match a " (optional)
)?         # Make the entire group optional
$          # End of string
```

Comment: @Vegeta: Good point, that shouldn't match. I added a little test suite as well :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var pattern = "^\d+(\'?(\d+\x22)?|\x22)$";
```

Comment: This also allows the empty string, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: @Vegeta:- Will not match `2"`

Comment: And if OP now checks which of the capturing group matched, if `2` is entered it will be captured by the "feet" group, not inches.

Answer (score 1):

Not to resurrect the dead, but here was my best shot at detecting fractional feet and inches. It will find:

- 3'
- 3'-1" or 3' 1"
- 3'-1 1/2" or 3' 1 1/2"
- 3'-1/2", 3' 1/2", 3'-0 1/2", or 3'0 1/2"
- 1"
- 1/2"

The only catch is your flavor of regex has to support conditionals.

```
pattern = "(\d+')?(?:(?(1)(?: |\-))(\d{1,2})?(?:(?(2) )\d+\/\d+)?\x22)?"
```