# Regex for validating a string format - Foot and Inch

Tags: regex, typescript, validation

I am trying to create a regex to validate the string is in below format.

```
[x' x" 1/4, x' x" 1/2, x' x" 3/4]
```

Valid examples:

- `5' 10" 1/2`
- `6' 3" 1/4`
- `4' 8"`
- `5'`
- `10"`

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Can you share your code/efforts? Also please add some invalid samples.

Comment: Similar question (__without fractions__) already answered: [Regex (JavaScript): match feet and/or inches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920506/regex-match-feet-and-or-inches). Possible duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(?!\s*$)(?:(?!0+')\d+')?(?: *(?!0+")\d+")?(?: *(?!0+\/)\d+\/(?!0+$)\d+)?$
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rtMQk5/3/)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(?!\s*$)` - negative lookahead to make sure that the current match is not followed by 0+ white-spaces followed by end of the string. This is to make sure that the regex should not match the empty strings or strings containing only white-spaces
- `(?:(?!0+')\d+')?` - matches 1+ digits followed by `'`. Also makes sure that it does not match something like `0'`. The `?` at the end makes this sub-match optional.
- `(?: *(?!0+")\d+")?` - matches 0+ spaces followed by 1+ digits followed by `"`. Also makes sure that it does not match something like `0"`. The `?` at the end makes this sub-match optional.
- `(?: *(?!0+\/)\d+\/(?!0+$)\d+)?` - matches 0+ spaces followed by fractions of the form `X/X` where X is a digit. Also, it does not match fractions of the form `0/6` or `0/0` or `8/0`.
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

Answer (score 2):

Based upon your samples, you can use this regex,

```
^\d+(?:'(?: +\d+"(?: +\d+\/\d+)?)?|")$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of input
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:'` - Noncapture group followed by singlequote
- `(?:` - Start of non-capture group
- `+\d+"` - Matches one or more space followed by one or more digits followed by doublequote
- `(?: +\d+\/\d+)?` - Matches one or more space followed by one or more digits then literal `/` then again one or more digits and whole of it is optional as it is placed inside non-capture group followed by `?`
- `)?` - Closing of previous non-capture group and `?` means even that group is optional
- `|")` - Alternation to support case where number can only be followed by double quote and close of group
- `$` - End of input

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kmDzof/3)**

Comment: Please note that `6" 3" 1/4` is a match.

Comment: @Matt.G: Handled that case as well.

Comment: @Matt.G: I've thought about it but as It's not listed, hence not supported. Indeed it would have been easier for me to support that. I've posted a comment for OP to list for invalid samples. Let's wait for OP to reply and then accordingly will further update as needed.

Comment: Super explanation and online-tests!

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `^(?:\d+')?(?: ?\d+"( ?\d+\/\d+)?)?$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kmDzof/4)

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript

You could simulate on [JavaScript Demo: RegExp Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Using_regular_expression_on_multiple_lines).

```js
var s = `5' 10" 1/2`;
var s1 = `6' 3" 1/4`;
var s2 = `4' 8"`;
var s3 = `5'`;
var s4 = `10"`;

var regex = /\d[\s\'\"\d\/]+/;

var result = s.match(regex);
var result1 = s1.match(regex);
var result2 = s2.match(regex);
var result3 = s3.match(regex);
var result4 = s4.match(regex);

console.log(result);
console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
console.log(result3);
console.log(result4);
```

Comment: Good effort to use the code-fiddle. The OP may learn __how to use RegEx in JavaScript__. Improve your answers by explanation, especially on complex RegEx. For __demo and testing__ you could use (http://regex101.com) and (http://regexPlanet.com) and share the link.

Comment: Typescript is related to Javascript. I preferred to run snippet. (You are earning reputation faster than me. I should edit more posts.)