# Feet inch regex of "universal" combinations

Tags: javascript, regex

So, there are plenty of questions and answers about standard ways of parsing feet and inches with regex. A casual search led me easily to:
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920506/regex-javascript-match-feet-and-or-inches)
[Link2](https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html)

But these options are very specific with what they are looking for and are not versatile enough for what I would want an expression to do. Desirably, I wanted a regex to match all ft inches dimensions like those below:

### Example matches (12 and 3 and 1/4 are just examples, matches should not be by line (not just $)):

- 12' 3"
- 12 feet 3 inches
- 12 ft 3 in
- 12 ft. 3 in.
- 12' -3"
- -12 feet 3 inches (Should capture the negatives)
- 12'- 3" (Should not mistaken as -ve 3, but not necessarily needed to be processed with regex)
- 12' 3 1/4"
- 12' 3.25"
- 12 ft 3 1/4 in.
- 12' (Need to capture "single" dimensions provided that it is not logically matched to next or prior)
- 3"
- 3 1/4 inches
- -3.25"
- 3 1/4feet

### Desired non-matches

- 12' 12'
- 3inches 12'
- 3 inches 3 inches (need to match separately = matches 3 inches twice)
- 3 - 2ft (need to be able to exclude the 3 and only match -2ft)

I started out trying to write something and came up with:

`/(-*[\d .]+(\/\d)* *){1}(?:FEET|FT\.*|'|INCH|INCHES|IN\.*|")+(?:[ -]*)/gi`

But it's too greedy and would accept 12' 12' as one thing. So I started doing some exclusions like what they did within Link 1 up there, but I couldn't get it such that it will work. I tried this:

`(-*[\d .]+(\/\d)* *){1}(?:FEET|FT\.*|'|INCH|INCHES|IN\.*|")+(?:[ -]*)(?!=(-*[\d .]+(\/\d)* *){1}(?:FEET|FT\.*|')+(?:[ -]*)){1,2}`

and also

`((?<!((-*[\d .]+(\/\d)* *){1}(?:INCH|INCHES|IN\.*|")+)))(-*[\d .]+(\/\d)* *){1}(?:FEET|FT\.*|'|INCH|INCHES|IN\.*|")+(?:[ -]*)(?!=(-*[\d .]+(\/\d)* *){1}(?:FEET|FT\.*|')+(?:[ -]*)){1,2}`

and I have tried some other approaches, such as

`(([-*\d+ *])+(?:FEET|FT\.*|')+(?:\s*-)*){0,1}((\s*\d+[./]*\d*\s*)+(?:INCH|INCHES|IN\.*|")+(?: )+){0,1}`

and it works the way I desired, but it also matches a lot of empty strings.

Maybe I am just not looking hard enough or searching the right terms, but I don't think I came across an old post that has something as versatile as I would have liked. If there has been an answer previously that does exactly what I would like, feel free to point it out for me. Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need to match `3inches 12'` as two matches: first `3inches` and then `12'`? Same question for `12' 12'`

Comment: Yes, correct! Will need those to match as two as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this regex based on the test cases provided:

```
/(?:-[ \t]*)?((?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|(?:\d+[ \t]+)?\d+[ \t]*\/[ \t]*\d+)[ \t]*(?:[']|feet|ft\.?)(?:[ \t]*(?:-[ \t]*)?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|(?:\d+[ \t]+)?\d+[ \t]*\/[ \t]*\d+)[ \t]*(?:["]|inch(?:es)?|in\.?))?|(?:(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|(?:\d+[ \t]+)?\d+[ \t]*\/[ \t]*\d+)[ \t]*(?:["]|inch(?:es)?|in\.?)))/g
```

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/4N2bGW/2)

Basically, the regex is constructed as such:

- `(?:-[ \t]*)?`: Optional negative sign
- `(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|(?:\d+[ \t]+)?\d+[ \t]*\/[ \t]*\d+)`: Matches whole number (e.g. `10`), real number (e.g. `3.45`), or fractional number (e.g. `3 1/4`, `10/4`). Let us denote this part as `<number>` so that we can see the bigger picture
- `<number>[ \t]*(?:[']|feet|ft\.?)`: Feet part. Number and unit optionally separated by space
- `<number>[ \t]*(?:["]|inch(?:es)?|in\.?)`: Inch part. Feet part. Number and unit optionally separated by space
- `(<feet part>(?:[ \t]*(?:-[ \t]*)?<inch part>)?|(?:<inch part>))`: Matches string with feet part and optional inch part (optionally separated by hyphen), or only inch part

The code assumes everything on a single line - if you want to match across lines, replace `[ \t]` with `\s`.

The regex will pick up valid substrings in non-matching cases - it only cares what it matches is valid, it doesn't care about the context of the match.